# Long listing values in directories and calculating values

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Write a shell script to display the long listing values using `awk` command but print the doubled value of a field and store as a separate field,
ex :

```
two text files a.txt,b.txt
```

#### I have

```
ls -l -g | awk print{ 2 * $2}
```

#### expected results:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root.usersgrp 120 dec 24 11.21 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 2 root.usersgrp 20 dec 24 11.22 b.txt
```

#### actual output needed

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root.usersgrp 20 dec 24 11.22 b.txt 40
```

here I need 40 is the doubled value of 20 in separate field

Comment: Hi, Welcome, Would you like to write your question properly so it makes sense for users to help you out? See here please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: write a shellscripting for displaying by doubling a field value and store it in a different field by using awk command

Comment: You have `print{ 2 * $2}` - maybe think about which field `$2` is and which field you want doubled. This is not a homework site so I will not give you the complete solution.

Comment: Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and then ask a question about what you're trying to do, not how you're trying to do it (see also http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```
/tmp> ls -l vgrs.txt data.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx yyyy  96 Dec 24 08:10 data.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx yyyy 148 Dec 24 08:02 vgrs.txt
/tmp> ls -l vgrs.txt data.csv | awk ' $(NF+1)=$5*2 '
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx yyyy 96 Dec 24 08:10 data.csv 192
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx yyyy 148 Dec 24 08:02 vgrs.txt 296
/tmp>
```

Explanation:

If you have n columns you can add one more column using $(NF+1) by manipulating existing columns.